# C#: Calculate win condition in console

Tags: c#, console

I got an assignment to program connect-4 in console. I have already programmed the board, but I am having a very hard time calculating the winner.
This is what I got so far:

```
        // Array play board
        int[,] intRaster = new int[6,7];

        // playboard
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t\t        1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n");
        string strTab = "\t\t\t\t";

        // Displays playboard
        for (int intX = 0; intX < 6; intX++)
        {
            Console.Write(strTab);
            for (int intY = 0; intY < 7; intY++)
            {
                Console.Write(intRaster[intX, intY]);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Input
        Label_0:
        Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t Speler 1: Maak uw zet!");

        // Player 1
        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString())
        {
            case "1":
                Console.Write("1");
                if (intRaster[0, 0] < 6)
                {
                    intRaster[0, 0]++;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 13 - intRaster[0, 0]);
                    Console.Write("1");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                }
                // Gives error message if player tries to put a disk in a 
                // full colom 
                else
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                    Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t ERROR: rij is vol!!!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                    goto Label_0;
                } 
        // Player 2
        Label_1:
        Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t Speler 2: Maak uw zet!");
        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString())
        {
            case "1":
                Console.Write("1");
                if (intRaster[0, 0] < 6)
                {
                    intRaster[0, 0]++;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 13 - intRaster[0, 0]);
                    Console.Write("2");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                    Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t ERROR: rij is vol!!!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 13);
                    goto Label_1;
                }
                goto Label_0;
```

So what I basicly did was declaring a 2 dimensional integer array [6,7]. 
The for loop will display the gameboard with the values of the array (which at the start would be 0 for every value).
Then the switch will read de character input of the player. If player 1 presses 1 the value 0 ([6, 0]) will be replaced by 1 etc...

Of course the switch contains more cases, but I left those out to shorten this code. So how do I calculate the winner horizontal, vertical and diagonally?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: just to be clear the intraster is an x,y representation of the board and contains the discs am I right? so when position 0,0 contains a 1 the disc belongs to player 1 correct?

Comment: Jelle Bleeker, yes you are correct! I can't figure out how to then calculate if a player 1 or 2 has reached 4 in a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, I got overexcited.. :-)

```
class Game
    {
        static int[,] intRaster = new int[6, 7];
        static int[] positionsDiskCount = new int[7];

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Array play board

            // playboard
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\t\t        1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n");
            string strTab = "\t\t\t\t";

            // Displays playboard
            for (int intX = 0; intX < 6; intX++)
            {
                Console.Write(strTab);
                for (int intY = 0; intY < 7; intY++)
                {
                    Console.Write(intRaster[intX, intY]);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Input
            while (true)
            {
                MakeMove(1);

                MakeMove(2);

            }
        }

        static private int MakeMove(int Player)
        {
            Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t Speler {0}: Maak uw zet!                        ", Player);
            int num = -1;
            bool moveMade = false;
            while (!moveMade)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    string key = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString();
                    if (key == "\u001b") Environment.Exit(0);
                    if (int.TryParse(key, out num) && num > -1 && num < 8) break;
                }
                num--;
                if (positionsDiskCount[num] < 6)
                {

                    intRaster[num, positionsDiskCount[num]] = Player;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(32 + num * 2, 9 - positionsDiskCount[num]);
                    Console.Write(Player);
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 10);

                    bool win = CheckWinner(num, positionsDiskCount[num]);
                    if (win)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    \n\n\t\t\t Speler {0} has won the game!!!!!!", Player);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                        Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }

                    positionsDiskCount[num]++;
                    moveMade = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 10);
                    Console.Write("    \n\n\t\t\t ERROR: rij is vol!!!   Maak uw zet!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 10);
                }
            }
            return num;
        }

        static public bool CheckWinner(int x, int y)
        {
            //Horizontal
            int count = countDirection(x, y, -1, 0);
            count += countDirection(x, y, 1, 0);
            if (count > 2) return true;
            count = countDirection(x, y, 0, -1);
            count += countDirection(x, y, 0, 1);
            if (count > 2) return true;
            count = countDirection(x, y, -1, -1);
            count += countDirection(x, y, 1, 1);
            if (count > 2) return true;
            count = countDirection(x, y, 1, -1);
            count += countDirection(x, y, -1, 1);
            if (count > 2) return true;
            return false;
        }

        static public int countDirection(int x, int y, int stepX, int stepY)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int Player = intRaster[x, y];
            x += stepX;
            y += stepY;
            while (x >= 0 && x < intRaster.GetUpperBound(1) && y >= 0 && y < intRaster.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
                if (Player == intRaster[x, y]) count++;
                else break;
                x += stepX;
                y += stepY;
            }
            return count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Aldert, you are a lifesaver! ;)

Comment: You are welcome, please study the code so you can learn from it and mark answer as accepted